# Найти наибольшую сумму значений вложенного словаря

Tags: python, циклы, словари

Подскажите пожалуйста, как через цикл перебрать словарь в списке, чтобы складывались значения ключа "qty" при одинаковых значениях ключа "price". То есть если 'price': '101' = 'price': '101' другого словаря, то тогда их 'qty': '845' + 'qty': '842' + 'qty': '840'
После чего нужно вывести значение ключа 'price' c наибольшей суммой значений 'qty'.

Вот сами словари в списке.

```
d = [{'id': 434557, 'price': '101', 'qty': '564', 'time': 1655981435709 }, 
{'id': 434558, 'price': '100', 'qty': '657', 'time': 1655981435709},
{'id': 434559, 'price': '101', 'qty': '845', 'time': 1655981435709}, 
{'id': 434560, 'price': '55', 'qty': '909', 'time': 1655981435709},
{'id': 434558, 'price': '100', 'qty': '657', 'time': 1655981435709},
{'id': 434559, 'price': '101', 'qty': '842', 'time': 1655981435709}, 
{'id': 434558, 'price': '100', 'qty': '657', 'time': 1655981435709},
{'id': 434559, 'price': '101', 'qty': '840', 'time': 1655981435709}]
```

Comment: Складывать надо по одинаковой цене? Или по одинаковому `id`?

Comment: Складывать нужно было по одинаковой цене, вы, Станислав, всё сделали правильно, спасибо Вам огромное ) И если Вам не трудно, посоветуйте литературу или сайты,  которые вы считаете наилучшими в плане обучения или прокачки знаний в области работы со словарями, а то я в интернете пол дня капался и ничего путного не нашёл. Ещё раз спасибо! )

Comment: Документация по языку: [5.5. Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), [Mapping Types — dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping), [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Требование складывать по одной цене выглядит очень подозрительно. Несмотря на это складываем количества в словаре `sums`, ищем пару с максимумом суммы, печатаем эту пару:

```
import collections


sums = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in d:
    sums[row['price']] += int(row['qty'])
print(*max(sums.items(), key=lambda p: p[-1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dt = {}
for a in d:
    try: dt[a['price']] += int(a['qty'])
    except: dt[a['price']] = int(a['qty'])

m = max(dt.values())
print([k for k in dt if dt[k] == m])
```

Answer (score 1):

если список словарей очень большой, то может быть оправданным использовать библиотеку pandas. тогда вывести значение ключа 'price' c наибольшей суммой значений 'qty' можно так:

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame(d).groupby('price')['qty'].agg(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum()).idxmax()

>>> res  # '101'
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, буду учитывать и этот вариант )